# Can we capture click activity of links in landing pages and generate reports based on the click activities of these links?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, landing-page

Can we capture click activity of links in landing pages that are used in emails ? Is there a way to generate reports based on the click activities of these links ? I can see Reports for landing pages in SFMC but these are opens/clicks activity of overall landing pages and not the links present in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 2024**: I have created a quite simple solution (easier to implement than the one previously suggested), allowing you to track clicks on Cloud Pages using a combination of SSJS/Ampscript and jQuery. It is quite easy to implement: https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/salesforce-marketing-cloud/tracking-clicks-on-outbound-links-from-cloud-pages/

It will automatically add an onclick listener to all href links, and store information about the clicked link, along with subscriber key and other attributes

---

You can't track outbound links from Cloud Pages, as they are not being redirected through the tracker domain, unlike links from emails. If you want, you can create a custom solution, where you will build your own redirect setup:

1. Build a cloud page which will automatically [redirect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirect.htm) based on a url provided as [requestparameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm)
2. This cloud page should upsert this URL to a data extension, along with the timestamp of the click and a unique identifier of the event (e.g. a guid)
3. All the links in your "original" cloud page will need to be created as [CloudPagesUrl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) in following way:

   %%=CloudPagesURL(ID, 'redirectTo', 'https://www.salesforce.com')=%%

Comment: I don't see any other way but every link click through this scenario will cost a super message for the cloud page impression on the way through to the final target URL. This could become pretty expensive if visitor volume and click behaviour is generally high or spikes for whatever reason. You should think about control mechanisms if this is foreseeable risk.

Comment: Fair point, and it is indeed worth noting. However, if the redirect can be built as a code resource, instead of a cloud page - it will not count towards super message utilisation.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I'm no developer but I'm wondering if it would be possible to design a lightweight script that can be used with onclick="function() " inside the <a> tag. If the script can capture the context data of the link tag it's used within there might be ways for a scalable solution that writes information to a data extension for every link that includes the onclick script. *scratching head